# Maven Could not find artifact after downloading from Nexus

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, nexus

we have got a problem. I set up job on jenkins and while building a project it fetches artifacts from nexus. But even though it downloaded them job failed with artifacts could not be found. It happened only to artifacts we manually imported to the nexus.

Any hints?

```
 [INFO] Downloading: http://xxx/nexus/content/groups/public/com/oracle/aqapi          /12.1.0.2/aqapi-12.1.0.2.pom
 [WARNING] The POM for com.oracle:aqapi:jar:12.1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
 [INFO] Downloading: http://xxx/nexus/content/groups/public/com/ibm/com.ibm.mq/7.1/com.ibm.mq-7.1.pom
 [WARNING] The POM for com.ibm:com.ibm.mq:jar:7.1 is missing, no dependency information available
 [INFO] Downloading: http://xxx/nexus/content/groups/public/com/ibm/com.ibm.dhbcore/7.1/com.ibm.dhbcore-7.1.pom
 [WARNING] The POM for com.ibm:com.ibm.dhbcore:jar:7.1 is missing, no dependency information available
 [INFO] Downloading: http://xxx/nexus/content/groups/public/com/oracle/aqapi/12.1.0.2/aqapi-12.1.0.2.jar
 [INFO] Downloading: http://xxx/nexus/content/groups/public/com/ibm/com.ibm.mq/7.1/com.ibm.mq-7.1.jar
 [INFO] Downloading: http://xxx/nexus/content/groups/public/com/ibm/com.ibm.dhbcore/7.1/com.ibm.dhbcore-7.1.jar
 Started calculate disk usage of build
 Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
 Started calculate disk usage of workspace
 Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
 ....
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.091s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 22 14:09:58 CET 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/491M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project YYY:jar:2.14.11: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.oracle:aqapi:jar:12.1.0.2, com.ibm:com.ibm.mq:jar:7.1, com.ibm:com.ibm.dhbcore:jar:7.1: Could not find artifact com.oracle:aqapi:jar:12.1.0.2 in nexus (http://xxx/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]`
```

Comment: The given artifacts are not in your repository manager...Have those artifacts uploaded into the `3rdparty` repository? If yes does your public contain thise `3rdparty` repository..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has not downloaded completely yet, you can check in `~/.m2/repository` for dependency.
Because its showing only "downloading" in actual case it will appear downloaded message.

1. first check for the n/w settings and internet.
2. if n/w is not the issue delete the `~/.m2` folder and retry once again

Comment: Thanks, seems it was not downloaded. Will be the n/w issue:

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the dependency in Nexus? 
Does Information in pom file in nexus correspond to your pom?

http://nexusUrl/nexus/content/repositories/central/checkstyle/checkstyle/4.1/checkstyle-4.1.pom

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>checkstyle</groupId>
                <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                <version>4.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                               ...
                </dependencies>
</project>
```

and in your pom:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>checkstyle</groupId>
                <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and check your settings for access to Nexus (settings.xml).